# How can I interrupt the mysqld front process?

Tags: linux, mysql

I want to ask, how is it possible to interrupt a simple mysqld command in the terminal.
By a mistake I typed in *mysqld* in the console and press enter.
Now I get  the Note that *mysqld* starting as a process (Process ID).
How can I interrupt such a command process in the future?
CTL - C, Z, \ and so on are not working here?

If you have a answer, it would be great to explain it also.

Comment: Open another shell and kill it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Ok I thought its possible in the same shell. Could you explain me, why it is not possible in the same shell? Is there no signal existing?

Comment: this is a normal behavior, since not all program can handle ctrl+c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

connect a second time and kill it
if its local, open a second terminal.

you can use

```sh
ps auxwww|grep mysql
kill -9 pid
```

or
if killall is available

```sh
killall -9 mysqld
```